# How to return a specific number pattern from array

Tags: javascript

I'm making a binary clock for fun (not an assignment or anything), where each time value is represented by a dot or "light". In short, I need to compare `getSeconds()` with 0-59 in an array, same for minutes and hours but the approach will be the same.

For this, I'd like to return certain values with as short code as possible from an array of integers between 0 and 59 so I've created a loop to return, say every other number, with `i =+ 2`.

Below code is not in my binary clock code, it's just to test this part of the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="test"></p>

<script>
var numberStart = 0;
var numberEnd = 59;
var text = "";
var arr = [];

for (var i = numberStart; i < numberEnd+1; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}

for (i = 2; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
text += arr[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, from this code I get:

```
2
4
6
...
58
```

In this example however, each time the second is 2, 3 and 6, 7 and 10, 11 and so on, the binary number 2 should "light up" together with other binary numbers of course but I solve for one at a time. Binary 4 should "light up" 4, 5, 6, 7 and 12, 13, 14, 15 etc and I figure there's a quick way to do that by grabbing the correct sequence of numbers from my array.

So I don't want it to return every other number, I need it to return a sequence of the same amount of numbers it loops through. Meaning for every loop run this example should return 2 and the next number, then skip the following 2, return that number and the next, skip 2 and continue like that until the loop ends. It's probably simple but I can't figure it out and whatever I try fails...

What I need when `i += 2`:

```
2, 3
6, 7
10, 11
...
58, 59
```

And when `i += 4`:

```
4, 5, 6, 7
12, 13, 14, 15
20, 21, 22, 23
etc
```

Comment: Be careful what you wish for, a very short version would be `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=[...Array(60).keys()].filter(i=>i&2).join('<br>')` (or, a bit better to understand: `i%4>1` instead of `i&2`)  Can you specify what this is used for and what the constraints are? Is this an assignment? I'm asking because it's not logical to use an array of consecutive integers in this case at all, yet you specifically ask for it, so it's not clear what the best solution _for you_ will be....

Comment: Hint: You can also increment `i` inside the loop after you process current group to create the skip of the next group

Comment: I've edited the question to include a quick summary what I'll use this for. It's not an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to increase by `4` after every iteration until the maximum is reached, so unless I misunderstood your question, you can simply do:

```js
const max = 58;
let text = "";
let current = 2;

while (current <= max) {
    text += `${current},${current + 1}<br>`;
    current += 4;
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does it. I got blinded by sticking to for-loops. Of course, your solution with while is much better!

Answer (score 0):

As per the question the following will provide the result as mentioned.

iterator will hold the value to increment.

```
const iterator = 4
for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; i += (iterator*2)) {
    for(let j = 0; j<iterator;j++){
       text += arr[i+j];
    }
    text+="<br>"
}
```

I think this will logic will help

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the most efficient way of doing this is to pre-calculate your array, so that you are then just doing a simple/direct lookup:

```
values = ["000", "001", "010", ... ];
```

I'm not clear on what you intend to do with the value, in order to "light up" your clock, but hopefully that is enough to explain what I mean?